# Prove Weierstrass theorem for a general $[a,b]$ follows from the result on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, weierstrass-approximation

Give a detailed proof of the assertion that the Weierstrass theorem for a general $[a,b]$ follows from the result on $[0,1]$ (by using lemma 11.1)

It's been two days since  I am trying to figure out the way of proving this problem in (N.L. Carothers), any hints please?

Comment: What is Lemma $11.1$? :)

Comment: You should provide some context. I doubt anyone will search for the book (that's assuming it's freely accessible) and find Lemma 11.1, then provide you with helpful remarks. That would be too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Start with $g \in C[a,b]$, from Lemma 11.1, there is $f \in C[0,1]$ such that $g(x) = f(t(x))$ where $t(x) = \frac{x-a}{b-a} \in [0,1]$.

Do the logical steps till you get:

$$\lVert g(x) - p_n (x) \rVert = \max_{a\le x \le b} |f(t(x)) - P_n(t(x))|=\max_{0\le t \le 1} |f(t) - P_n(t)| < \epsilon.$$

That is because we have already know that the space of polynomials is dense in $C[0,1]$.